# 6-letter words of ABC so "AAB" does NOT appear

Tags: combinatorics

**Question: find the number of 6 letter words with letters A, B, and C such that the string of letters "AAB" does not appear in the word.**

I don't know how to attack this problem. I know I'm supposed to use the inclusion-exclusion principle or something similar, but I don't know how to set the problem up.

Any pointers? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Count the words in which the string AAB **does** appear. This is fairly easy, since apart from the word AABAAB, the words containing AAB contain exactly one copy of that substring; you can use a very simple case of inclusion-exclusion to do this. Then subtract from the total number of $6$-letter words formed with A, B, and C.

Answer (score 1):

Since there are 3 ways to fill up each position of the letters.Total number of possible words =

$3\times3\times\cdots = 3^{6}$

Now consider the case in which we have the string 'AAB'.The number of ways to fill up the rest of the 3 positions =$3^{3}$

The string 'AAB' can be kept in any of the 4 possible places.(At the beginning,in between letters 1 and 2,in between letters 2 and 3,at the last).

So the total number of cases we need to neglect = $4\times 3^{3}$

Finally we need to add the case 'AABAAB' since we have neglected it twice.

Answer: $$3^{6}-4\times 3^{3}+1$$